# Exponential manipulation: is $8^x-2^x=(8 - 2)^x$ valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Given: $8^x-2^x$.  I saw someone manipulate this as $(8 - 2)^x$.
I wasn't sure if this was correct.

If it is, what exponential rule exactly allows one to do this?

I understand $(8^x)/(2^x) = (8/2)^x$, but not the first technique. Thanks.

Comment: "someone manipulate this". Who did that? It is false in general: look at the case $x=2$.

Comment: You're right. Unless $x=1$, you have $8^x-2^x\neq(8-2)^x$ (LHS bigger for $x>1$ and smaller when $x<1$)

Comment: Thank you, Ipz and user 1046533.  As I suspected, the technique was incorrect.  Always good to get a "sanity-check".  In fact, I had checked the manipulation just as you did: using the case x = 2.

Comment: As pointed out, it is wrong. For example $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ and not $(a-b)^2$. You could however manipulate it like this: $8^x+2^x=(2\cdot 4)^x+2^x=2^x4^x+2^x=2^x(4^x+1)$.

Comment: That operation is illegal. However, the person who does that may be intentional. He/She may be demonstrating the [Freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream)

Answer (score 2):

I always like to try an example or two to see whether or not a statement is true. Does
$$8^x-2^x=(8-2)^x$$
when $x=2$?

$$
\begin{align*}
\color{#0a0}{8^x-2^x}&=\color{#c00}{(8-2)^x}\\
\color{#0a0}{8^2-2^2}&=\color{#c00}{(8-2)^2}\\
\color{#0a0}{64-4}&=\color{#c00}{6^2}\\
\color{#0a0}{60}&\ne \color{#c00}{36}
\end{align*}
$$
So, we know the statement is certainly not true in general.

Comment: Thank you, Clyde.   I did the exact thing when I had my doubts about the manipulation. Always helps to get a second opinion.

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: Is $x = 1$ the only solution in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Not sure, I think that's a much more difficult question to answer.